# How create custom clasifier with hierarchy - watson visual recognition

Tags: watson, visual-recognition

I am working with Watson Visual Recognition and have successfully created a custom classifier.

I notice the build in default classifier can return a hierarchy eg: Animals/Dog, But how to create a custom classifier return response contains "type_hierarchy" such as default classifier ?

It may be necessary to train a custom classifier with more positive class and negative class or it is possibly due to me being on the trial version  ?!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multi level hierarchy in the default classifier is a special feature of that classifier.  You cannot create a hierarchy within a custom classifier. This is true of both free and paid plans. However, in a custom classifier, you get to specify the name of each class, so you could include hierarchical information in each class name, for example "animals_dog_beagle" could be a class name.

Note that classes within a classifier should be mutually exclusive, since the learner uses the positive examples from one class as the negative examples of the others. (Along with any explicitly given negative examples)